# Serialize C++ class to file, then event-based deserialization in Python?

Tags: python, c++, serialization, swig, ramdisk

I have C++ source code for a function that mutates a complex object. Without reverse engineering or otherwise studying its class, how could I serialize it to a file (perhaps on a mounted ramdisk) and then easily deserialize it in Python? Do I need Swig to do this?

I just want to add a line of code or two to C++ source (right after the object is mutated), generate a Linux user signal or something each time the file is updated, and install a Python handler for that custom signal which deserializes the file and does something with the object.

Simpler inter-language, inter-process techniques for accomplishing this are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) to save complex data in C++ and read it in python. There is libraries for both language, and because of protobuf enough popular you easy enough find help about its usage.

Comment: Looks like there's no easy way to take existing c++ code and "extend" it with protobuf. It seems usual workflow is 1) define message in .proto file, 2) use special compiler to generate c++ header/implementation files. It would be helpful to have something that can generate .proto from a web of .h files